# crop.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `(' crop.sh: line 3: `foreach file (`ls *.pdf`)'

Tags: bash, sh, unexpected-token

In what follows, I have written my bash file, crop.sh. However, I get this error when I run it in windows. I used cygwin. I also installed git and used mingw64. I searched a lot but couldn't solve this issue.

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach file (`ls *.pdf`)

 pdfcrop --ini $file $file

end
```

The error message is:

```
crop.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
crop.sh: line 3: `foreach file (`ls *.pdf`)'
```

Comment: You are trying to execute a C shell script with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: If you have `#!/bin/csh` as a shebang, this is not a bash script.

Comment: Even without `#!/bin/csh`, it's still not a `bash` script :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a `bash` tag and mention `bash`, but your code is `csh`.  Not sure if you want a `bash` solution, or to fix your csh, but you can certainly do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.pdf; do
   pdfcrop --ini "$file"  "$file"
done
```

Since `csh` is generally considered to be unsuited for scripting, this is probably a good route to take.

Answer (score 1):

Danger, Will Robinson. It's not uncommonly held that [csh is considered harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html).

That said, you can ([SHOULD!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)) use globs instead of parsing the output of ls, regardless of your shell. I haven't seen your filenames, but I suspect the issue might be a non-standard character in a filename.

Instead, try this:

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach file ( *.pdf )

  pdfcrop --ini "$file" "$file"

end
```

Or even better, do it in POSIX shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.pdf; do
    pdfcrop --ini "$file" "$file"
done
```